# Need to have different CSS for safari, chrome and firefox

Tags: cross-browser

I've realised that my css won't work the same way in different browsers. Especially width and position differentiates between the browsers.

I've come to understand that telling the browser to chose different stylesheets depending on which browser's used isn't preferable. But how do I code things otherwise if I am to do it all in the same stylesheet?

Right now I'm struggling the most with an `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave` animation where I can't position things to work even somehow correctly in all browsers.

I'm using em's to define distances/sizes, in case that would matter.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas for your reference:

1. It's really true that Self-created css and javascript may not support different browsers very well all the time, that's why ppl shift to use css framework(such as bootstrap) and javascript libraries (jquery etc).
2. but if you don't want to use framework, then u may do css hack to your css. 
   such as css piority overrides, 
   browser compatibility / detection tags is widely used.
3. @media query & reloading page for different css on different resolutions (used in many responsive sites)